# Custom setter in mvc auto db first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a User model that is auto generated DB-First in my MVC application using Entity Framework

```
User
  +Username
  +Password
```

I want to modify the setter of `"Password"` field so that it will be SHA256 incrypted before it is stored in the db.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: Please, use [blowfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_(cipher)) instead.

Comment: This doesn't change the need for a custom setter for an auto-generated code, the question was about that not about the Cipher Algorithm.

Comment: which is why it was an comment and not an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i've seen done for codefirst is make the setter private and add a method called SetPassword. I'm not sure this is possible with Db First.  Considering you should probalby update the users password salt at the same time having it as a method instead of a property setter makes sense.

Comment: so this method suppose to go into a partial class ? because the original l file is auto-generated..